# jQuery find element in ul li span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML structure as:

```
<div title="" class="interestareascategories_chn chzn-container chzn-container-multi">
    <ul id="ul_deptType" class="chzn-choices">
        <li id="li_dept_1" ver="old" class="search-choice"> <span>DEV</span>    <a rel="3" class="search-choice-close" seq="1" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>

        </li>
        <li id="li_dept_2" ver="old" class="search-choice"><span>QA</span>  <a rel="3" class="search-choice-close" seq="2" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>

        </li>
        <li id="selD7J_chzn_c_3" class="search-choice"><span>sag</span>     <a class="search-choice-close" seq="0.19415735425269753" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>

        </li>
        <li class="search-field"><span contenteditable="true" style="width: 25px;"></span>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How to get only `seq` in anchor tag which have `rel` attribute?

Comment: what you tried? what you want if element have rel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple and straightforward answer:

```
// gets all anchors with attribute rel and place their [seq] values into an array
var values = $.map($('a[rel]'), function(el){
  return el.getAttribute('seq');
});

console.log(values); // ["1", "2"]
```

[live code sample](http://jsbin.com/mobuzinu/1/edit)

Comment: can i find the text of span who doesn't have rel attribute in anchor tag i.e sag only

Comment: yeah, using the $('a[rel]').prev()

Answer (score 1):

You can use next selector for specific `rel` value

```
var seq3 = $("a[rel='3']").attr("seq");
```

To get sum of all sequences use next:

```
var sum = 0;
$.each($("a[rel='3']"), function(i, el)
                     {
                        sum += el.getAttribute("seq") | 0                         
                     })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var anchor = $('a[rel][seq]'); // this only targets anchors which have these 
                               // rel and seq attributes.
```

---

You can try this:

```
$('a[rel][seq]').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).attr('seq'));
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dZHd/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var seq = $("a[rel]").attr("seq");
```

Comment: doesn't this only get one value?

Comment: $("a[rel]") should return all a tags with rel attribute, if you want to iterate through all it's sql attributes you could do something like $("a[rel]").each(function () { $(this).attr("seq"); });

Answer (score 0):

You you want seq attribute of all anchors that have rel attribute then:

try like this:

```
    $("a.search-choice-close").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('rel')) {
          alert($(this).attr('seq'));
        }
    })
```

or :

```
 $("a.search-choice-close[rel]").each(function(){
         alert($(this).attr('seq'));     
  })
```

[demo fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/80/)
[demo fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/81/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`has attribute selector`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) for `rel` and the get the value of `seq` attribute on the selected elements.

Code:

```
$('a[rel]').each(function(i,e){
    console.log($(this).attr('seq'))
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/VU3hr/

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){{
   var check=jQuery(".search-choice a ").attr("rel");
   if(check!="undefined")
   {
      var selVar=jQuery(this).attr("seq");
   }

})
```

you should write a script like this, you can also store all "seq" value in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/U2s7f/1/

```
$("a[rel]").map(function(i, el) { return $(el).attr("seq"); })
```