# Jquery find elements

Tags: jquery

```
How to find the span text Achievements, QA , Dept having parent span Talk using Jquery.
```

im supposed to generate dynamic html like below with different parent span text and save the li>span values in database

> ```
> <span class="chntxt">Talk(parent)</span>
>
> <div title="" class="elemenaryschool_chn chzn-container chzn-container-multi">
>
> <ul class="chzn-choices">
>
> <li seq="1" subseq="1" id="58" class="search-choice">
> <span>Achievements</span>
> <a rel="3" class="search-choice-close" href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
>
> <li seq="1" subseq="2" id="59" class="search-choice">
> <span>QA</span> 
> <a rel="3" class="search-choice-close" href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
>
> <li seq="1" subseq="3" id="60" class="search-choice">
> <span>Dept</span> 
> <a rel="3" class="search-choice-close" href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
>
> <li class="search-field"><span contenteditable="true" style="width: 25px;"></span></li>
>
> </ul></div>
> ```

Comment: question not clear.. rephrasing needed.

Comment: try to make a answer from your last question : [jQuery find element in ul li span](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712072/jquery-find-element-in-ul-li-span)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can select the spans themselves. I'm assuming by saying you "have parent span Talk" that you want to traverse the tree from that start point. Here's what I came up with:

```
jQuery('.chntxt').on('click', function(){
    jQuery(this).nextAll().find('span').css('border', '1px solid red');
});
```

The .css() is just to show what is being selected. You could change that to .text() and use .each() to store them all as variables or in an array or something.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use jQuery to find objects, you can use jQuery.find()

http://api.jquery.com/find/

$( "span" ).parent().find( "li" ).css( "background-color", "red" );